# How to process every two-character substrings of a String in Swift 2.2+?

Tags: swift, swift2

C-style for loops are not supported anymore, so how would this old hex-decoder look like in Swift 2.2+?

```
let data = NSMutableData(capacity: trimmedString.characters.count / 2)
for var index = trimmedString.startIndex; index < trimmedString.endIndex; index = index.successor().successor() {
    let byteString = trimmedString.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: index, end: index.successor().successor()))
    let num = UInt8(byteString.withCString { strtoul($0, nil, 16) })
    data!.appendBytes([num] as [UInt8], length: 1)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `stride`:

```
for index in 0.stride(through: trimmedString.characters.count, by: 2) {
    // ...
}
```

To create the `Range` from the `index`, use the `startIndex` of the string and advance it.  Example:

```
trimmedString.startIndex.advancedBy(index)
trimmedString.startIndex.advancedBy(index).successor().successor()
```

etc.  Just check to make sure you aren't going out of bounds with `successor()`.

Answer (score 0):

Most loops like this can be implemented with the `stride` method, but `String.CharacterView.Index` is not `Strideable`. You could use the `enumerate` method to create an integer-based index alongside the string indices, and then use a `where` clause to only execute the loop every second time:

```
for (i, index) in trimmedString.characters.indices.enumerate() where number % 2 == 0 {
    print(trimmedString.characters[i])
}
```